# How many ways are there to choose 2 numbers such that their product is a multiple of 3

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let A be the set A = {1; 2; 3; ... ; 20} containing natural numbers from 1 to 20.

How many ways are there to choose 2 numbers for A such that their product is a multiple of 3?

I tried to take the set B = {3; 6; 9; 12; 15; 18} and taking the combination C(6,1), and C(20, 1). Then I took their product, but I did not succeed.

Can anyone help me overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to specify "replacement" or not.  That is, can we choose $5$ twice?  Your method counts  pairs like $(3,6)$ twice.

Comment: There is no restriction from that point.

Comment: ok. so, to stick with your method, there are three types of solutions:  Either $(multiple, not\;multiple)$, $(not\;multiple, multiple)$, or $(multiple, multiple)$. Each type is easily counted.  First type, say, has $6\times 14$ instances.

Comment: Also:  does the order matter?  Is $(4,8)$ the same solution as $(8,4)$?

Comment: @lulu The order should not matter. Because we are just choosing numbers. The order does not make anything different.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to compute the number of ways to choos two numbers such that their product is not a multiple of $3$: since $3$ is prime, it is sufficient to pick two numbers not divisible by $3$.

I make two cases: the two numbers are distinct, or they are equal.

First case: the two numbers are distinct. The non-multiples of $3$ are $14$, so you have $\binom{14}{2}$ pairs of distinct numbers non-multiple of $3$. So, you have $\binom{20}{2} - \binom{14}{2} = 190-91 = 99$ ways to pick two distinct numbers whose product is a multiple of $3$.

Second case: the two numbers are equal. This gives us $6$ ways (picking twice the same multiple of $3$).

Hence, in total, you have $99+6=105$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that the product is a multiple of $3$ is that either one or both of the chosen numbers are multiples of $3$.

From $1$ to $20$, there are $6$ multiples of $3$ as you have mentioned in set B.

Now you have to select $1$ of those $6$ numbers and the other number can be any one of the $20$ numbers.

So the total number of ways $= 6 \times 20 = \color{blue}{120}$.

But then my calculation involves twice the numbers where both the factors are multiples of $3$.

But there should be actually $\binom{6}{2}$ such products, where both the factors are multiples of $3$.

Hence the answer i.e. the required total number of ways $= 120 - \binom{6}{2} =120 - 15 = \color{red}{105} $

Comment: Good job ;) we were both wrong at the beginning.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks.. :-)